Alter object’s transform so its parent’s matches its child’s
Going insane over this. I’m trying to figure out a way so that when I grab an object, I can set the rotation & position of that object such that the rotation and position of the original object’s parent, matches the rotation and position of the original object's child as if the parent was a child of the original object too. ChatGPT gave me this code, but it's giving completely different results depending on initial rotations/positions, where the object is grabbed, or something. It reparents on each grab if that has anything to do with it.
{
        // Reparent objectA to objectB
        objectA.SetParent(objectB);

        // Calculate the world position and rotation of objectC
        Vector3 objectCWorldPosition = objectC.position;
        Quaternion objectCWorldRotation = objectC.rotation;

        // Calculate the local position and rotation needed for objectA
        Vector3 localPosition = objectA.InverseTransformPoint(objectCWorldPosition);
        Quaternion localRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(objectA.rotation) * objectCWorldRotation;

        // Apply the local position and rotation to objectA to match objectC's world position and rotation
        objectA.localPosition = localPosition;
        objectA.localRotation = localRotation;
    }

This code gives different results each time, but I just want it to be the same every time, so that no matter where and how you grab the original object, it appears the same in the parent object (which is the hand)
I've been running the same prompts through ChatGPT and it gives slightly modified answers each time but they all tend to have the same results.

Im not in unity to check , but my brain is saying the childs rotation is relative to the parents so if it says its 45 degrees, and the parent is already 90, its actually 135, the question is why allow moving of the child not use the parent/

Okay, so what I have is an object that I want to pick up. When picked up, it needs to be parented to the hand in order to follow the hand. I'm able to set the position alone using Vector3 direction = localTransformOverride.position - palmTransform.position; Vector3 desiredPosition = palmTransform.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position-direction); However, I can't correctly set the rotation. It's supposed to match the rotation of the localTransformOverride in worldSpace (or, as though the parent and the child were both children of the object and equal)

OK but you only need to know how much to rotate the object so the hand fits on it, unless you're expecting to do some kinda hand twizzling where it spins 360 degrees in a hand :P in which case you set the child to the fixed known offset while in the hand, then, to unparent it, you point it to the parent rotation + offset

That's the problem I'm having though, is how to find out how much to rotate the object to ensure that it's rotated in the hand in the same way that the child is rotated, so the hand and the child end up in the same rotation relative to the object being grabbed

the hand shouldnt be matching the object, the object should match the hand, so for example, if my hand is like when you type if i grabbed a pen it would run roughly 90 deegrees off..

No, the object needs to be rotated in such a way that the rotation of the object's child and the rotation of the hand match. The object is what is being rotated, but it must be rotated until its child is rotated in the same direction as the hand.

OK so you still need to work out (like the pen senaio) that it would be offset by x degrees, then you can take soon to be childs rotation, apply the opposite of the offset, eg if +90, you want -90, and apply that to the hand, then attach the child to the hand and set the offset

There are things about this that I cannot change. I'm working in a specific framework. When you pick up an object, it parents to the hand. I cannot rotate or affect the hand. On the object, there is a transform that is the desired hand position and rotation. I can figure out how to get the object to move so that the desired hand position moves to the actual hand position, but I can't get the object to rotate so the worldspace rotation of the desired hand position matches the actual rotation of the actual hand. Like, in the scene view, the hand and the desired hand position/rotation must match.

Like, ClaudeAI gave me this:
Quaternion desiredObjectRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(desiredHandRotation.rotation) * pickedUpObject.rotation;
pickedUpObject.rotation = palmTransform.rotation * desiredObjectRotation; But this doesn't work. The rotation it gives is different depending on the initial conditions of the object or the hand.

You said to rotate the hand. I can't do that. If it's such simple math, explain the math, because nothing I have tried from any source can come close.

You don't seem to understand what I'm asking. I can't move the hand. When it grabs an object, that object parents to the hand, and then that object, now parented to the hand, also has its own child transform. I need to rotate the object, with the child transform, until the child transform has the same rotation that the hand has. There is no rotation of the hand happening at all. the object rotates until its child transform has the same rotation as the hand. That hand doesn't align to anything. The object rotates until its child aligns with the hand.

If anyone finds this and needs help, here is the solution that I found. It's not simply enough to find the difference in rotation and apply that to the object. ChatGPT said to do this:
transform.rotation *= parentObject.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(child.rotation)

However, that doesn't work. You get random rotations each time. The solution I found (with assistance from an awesome pro) was that you need to adjust the rotation to for each of the axes, and since that changes the target position each time, you need to adjust the position after each rotation move. So it looks more like this:
Quaternion rotationOffset = Quaternion.FromToRotation(refUp, handUp);
transform.rotation = rotationOffset * transform.rotation;
// Fix Position
Quaternion rotationOffset = Quaternion.FromToRotation(refForward, handForward);
transform.rotation = rotationOffset * transform.rotation;
// Fix Position
Quaternion rotationOffset = Quaternion.FromToRotation(refRight, handRight);
transform.rotation = rotationOffset * transform.rotation;
// Fix Position

You might even have to repeat this a few times, since each adjustment affects the last, but it will get it into roughly the right place within a few tries. I hope this is able to help.

Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. I wouldn't mention ChatGPT in your answer. People get touchy about that around here. The comment isn't really relevant to the answer anyway. Perhaps you could consider removing that part.
